# Using touchpunch with JQuery UI Accordion Sortable does not work correctly with touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-touch-punch

I just created a sortable Accordion with JQuery UI and used [touchpunch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) to enable touch devices to sort the sections. 
Drag and drop works fine, but I noticed that "touch-to-extend" does not always work and i have to touch a few times to make the section extend.

Does anyone know a fix for this?

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
    <div id="accordion">
      <div class="group">
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
        <div>
          <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
        <div>
          <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <h3>Section 3</h3>
        <div>
          <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui. </p>
          <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <h3>Section 4</h3>
        <div>
          <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia mauris vel est. </p><p>Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <script>

    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" )
          .accordion({
            header: "> div > h3"
          })
          .sortable({
            axis: "y",
            handle: "h3",
            stop: function( event, ui ) {
              // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting
              // so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
              ui.item.children( "h3" ).triggerHandler( "focusout" );

              // Refresh accordion to handle new order
              $( this ).accordion( "refresh" );
            }
          });
      });
    </script>
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxvoyw6x/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Ya the problem is that the sortable is triggering on mouse down or click or something, and touchpunch is overriding the defualt action. Without going through the code, I just made a little "hack" where I separated the sort handle from the h3 element.

Step 1:
set up some styles so the icon is in the right place

```
.dragme {
    float:right;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

Step 2: 
put that icon in and make it pretty

```
<h3>Section 3<span class='dragme  ui-accordion-icons ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s'></h3>
```

Step 3: change the sortable handle so that nice looking icon moves stuff

```
 .sortable({
            axis: "y",
            handle: ".dragme"});
```